# Android: access database using different thread

Tags: android, database

I have a class "A" that has to setup table according to data from DB. Managing database is done using class "B". Class "B" has method "getAllData" that returns a cursor. So, class "A" calls "getAllData" from class "B", and using returned cursor it populates tablelayout with data. It works, but there's a problem -> it works so slow! I want to query my DB using another thread.
Googling around i found something about "AsyncQueryHandler" but i'm puzzled. When "AsyncQueryHandler" gets a cursor (reads data from DB), how can i notify class "A" that data is ready? How can i return cursor from "AsyncQueryHandler" to class "A"?

Answer (score 0):

Looking here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html

After calling startQuery, you can implement onQueryComplete to pass on the cursor.  It will be called once the query is complete.